# display the names who passed in subject 'M' but fail in subject 'P'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table Student
(
  Name varchar(20),
  Subject varchar(20),
  Mark int
)

insert into Student values('A','M',30),
                          ('A','P',45),
                          ('B','M',47),
                          ('B','P',70)

SELECT * FROM Student
```

above is the code for the table. Consider the pass mark=35
need to display the name who pass in subject 'P' but fail in subject 'M'

Comment: Please show your best attempt at figuring out this query independently.

Comment: At least show some effort, and also add the expected results as formatted text

Comment: Just google sql where clause and also where in combination with and/or, [here is one place to learn](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you say, you need the student who pass in subject `'P'` and in the same time fail in subject `'M'`

```
SELECT Name
FROM Student
WHERE Subject = 'P' AND Mark >= 35
AND Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Student WHERE Subject = 'M' AND Mark < 35);
```

Results:

```
+----+------+
|    | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
+----+------+
```

Or even

```
SELECT *
FROM Student S1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Student S2
    WHERE S1.Name = S2.Name AND 
          ((S1.Mark > 35 AND S2.Mark < 35) OR (S2.Mark > 35 AND S1.Mark < 35))

)
```

Results:

```
+----+------+---------+------+
|    | Name | Subject | Mark |
+----+------+---------+------+
|  1 | A    | M       |   30 |
|  2 | A    | P       |   45 |
+----+------+---------+------+
```

**[Demo](https://rextester.com/WPSOUL82468)**

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Name
FROM Student
group by Name
having
min(case when Subject = 'M' then Mark end) < 35
and
min(case when Subject = 'P' then Mark end) >= 35
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Exists`

```
select * from Student s where exists(select 1 from Student s1
                                where s1.Name=s.Name
                                group by s1.Name
                                having sum(case when s1.Subject='P' and s1.Mark>=35 then 1 else 0 end)>0
                                 and sum(case when s1.Subject='M' and s1.Mark<35 then 1 else 0 end)>0
                                 ) 

Name    Subject Mark
A        M      30
A        P      45
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=75a87ee4230001794b3add23a3a17231)

Answer (score 0):

#### Please check this query

```
SELECT Name, M, P  
 FROM  
 (SELECT Name, Subject, Mark   
    FROM Student) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
AVG(Mark)  
FOR Subject IN (M, P)  
) AS PivotTable
WHERE M < 35 and P >= 35
```